# Is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\log\log2)^n}{n!}>\frac{3}{5}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I tried to find bounds for the sum using regular techniques, but couldn't get any result nor contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

This is nothing else than the expression for $e^{\ln\ln2}=\ln2\simeq0.693>\frac35=0.6$. I'm referring here, of course, to the famous identity $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Even without the knowledge the LHS is an expansion of $e^{\log\log 2}$, the fact
$\log\log 2 \sim -0.3665$ allows one to conclude the LHS is an alternating series with monotonic decreasing magnitudes. This already give us a good enough lower bound for LHS:
$$\text{LHS} \ge 1 + \log\log2 \sim 0.6335 > \frac{3}{5}$$